# Efficiency of std::min in c++

Tags: c++, performance, stl, std, min

I was implementing Floyd-Warshall's algorithm in c++, for an MOOC on Coursera, in C++. I was using std::min to find minimum between the current distance between two nodes and that with a jump included (according to the standard pseudo code of the algorithm.)
I found that use of std::min increased runtime of my program compared to use of if condition.

e.g.

```
if(a[i][j] > a[i][k]+a[k][j])
  a[i][j] = a[i][k]+a[k][j];
```

instead of 
`a[i][j] = min (a[i][j], a[i][k] + a[k][j]);`

I ran both these programs with these test-cases https://github.com/beaunus/stanford-algs/tree/master/testCases/course4/assignment1AllPairsShortestPath and found that on larger test-cases, code with std::min took twice to thrice time compared to the code with if conditions.

[I'm aware that a similar question has already been asked, but that does have any real answer.]
edit:
I have marked "HERE" where I substituted the if conditions for "std::min" and the performance difference was noticeable.
The complete code is here:

```
    //This implements Floyd Warshall algorithm for all pairs- shortest paths.
#include<cstdio>
#include<algorithm>
const int INF=10000, NMAX=2048; //According to the constraints of the test-files.
using namespace std;
int A[NMAX+1][NMAX+1];

int main()
{
    int n, m;   //n= number of vertices, m = number of edges in the directed graph.
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);
    //Initializing array of distances.
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {   for(int j=1; j<=n; j++)
        {   A[i][j]=INF;        //This makes distance from every node to every other node = INF.
        }
        A[i][i]=0;              //distance from every node to itself is zero.
    }

    //Taking input of m edges and storing them.
    int x, y, dist;
    for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
    {   scanf("%d %d %d",&x,&y,&dist);

        if(A[x][y]>dist)        // HERE.
            A[x][y]=dist;       // There is an edge with weight "dist", tail x and head y.
    }

    for(int k=1; k<=n; k++)
    {   for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
        {   for(int j=1; j<=n; j++)
            {   if(A[i][j] > A[i][k]+A[k][j])   //HERE.
                    A[i][j] = A[i][k]+A[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

    //This finds the minimum distance in shortest paths.
    int mindist=0, mini, minj;
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {   if(A[i][i]<0)           //This happens iff there is negative cycle.
        {   printf("NULL\n");
            return 0;
        }
        for(int j=1; j<=n; j++) //Find the min shortest path distance between any pair of nodes.
        {   if(mindist > A[i][j])    //HERE
            {   mindist= A[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",mindist);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which compiler do you use? Which optimization level? Other settings?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Which is the type of `a` ?

Comment: To Nickey C,
I use gcc (Ubuntu 6.3.0-12ubuntu2) 6.3.0 20170406 with no specified optimization (i.e. default options).

Answer (score 1):

The main difference here is in the second form you are (essentially) forcing an update of every element (though it may be a no change update).

In the first version you only perform updates required.

It depends on your architecture but if the array is large and the number of cases where the second term is smaller is relatively low you could be causing unnecessary memory writes.

One way to investigate that is replace `min` with a conditional operator `?:`.
If that's the case performance will be about the same because the overhead isn't in `min()` it's in unnecessarily writing the value of `a[i][j]` over itself.

You might also consider creating a reference to `a[i][j]` as:

```
auto &v(a[i][j]);
```

To help minimize index calculations (the optimizer may do this for you but you can't hurt it).

```
auto &v(a[i][j]);
if(v > a[i][k]+a[k][j]) {
  v = a[i][k]+a[k][j];
}
```

NB: With regard to this local reference. Any reasonable compiler should (with optimization on) spot this and emit what amounts to the same code. But if you're not familiar with optimization and learning it may not be the time to go into that. The common objection to hand optimizing is readability. I'd argue in the case the optimized version is if any more readable anyway.

Comment: Note that, unless `a` is declared `volatile`, you are not really *forcing* writes here. The compiler would be allowed to optimize the writes away under the as-if rule (although [it seems that current mainstream compilers don't do this](https://godbolt.org/g/c9rNCg)).

Comment: @ComicSansMS When I say 'force' I'm not necessarily talking about to main memory. It's marking cache somewhere. It's an effect that I've seen directly and here on SO where for large arrays because that requires a scan of (potentially) many cache lines the 'phoney' writes cause delay. As I said depends on details of the architecture but can be avoided.

Comment: Fair enough, but as I said, the compiler would be allowed to emit identical code for both cases. There is no need emit a write here at all, if the compiler can prove that you are just overwriting with the same value you read before from the same memory location.

Comment: @ComicSansMS: It could if it can optimize its way through all that. I've certainly seen cases where it doesn't or can't. It isn't obvious that `x=x>y?y:x;` is any more efficient than `if(x>y){x=y;}` except when you consider algorithms doing relatively few updates on large arrays and look at how that may affect memory caching. If x is a single variable probably makes no difference!
For my experience and others that is too much to expect of an optimizer in 2017.

Comment: I completely agree. I was merely trying to point out that such an optimization would be theoretically possible and legal with regards to the standard.

Comment: Which? Using a temporary? Definitely. I'd expect the optimizer to pick that out. But we're dealing with an OP learning C++ and on 30 rep. IMHO I've offered the right lesson to the student today. Going down a rabbit hole of telling OP to turn on optimization and/or review the assembler is a step too far I think.

Comment: Hence only a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @ComicSansMS I'll amend the answer.